# How to store multipart form data attachment in azure storage account from Azure APIM with filename

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-storage-account

Our Mobile App is uploading user attachments and storing it in an SQL table using a function App backend API. We now want to change the flow to MobApp-APIM-Storage Account. We have been able to store and retrieve the attachments through APIM and Storage Account APIs but are struggling with attachment information.

[Policy Expressions for Storing and retrieving images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eYqT.png)

Foll is how the input looks

POST
Request-Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=oUBB7xpVogYp5Ye.iuLqgWTuE-4P0ViXB6_GTvp1g78MCdQtHRrKCy-DHRF0MNM2eGEW_Z

--oUBB7xpVogYp5Ye.iuLqgWTuE-4P0ViXB6_GTvp1g78MCdQtHRrKCy-DHRF0MNM2eGEW_Z
content-disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="other-doc.jpg"
content-type: image/jpeg

����...`��

We need to store (if required) separately as metadata and return these fields in response as follows

Get Attachment Response
{
"attachmentName": "optionaldoc2.jpg",
"attachmentType": "jpg",
"attachmentData": "/9j/4AAQSkZ.....HoACSDSIAo//Z",
"createdAt": "2022-11-19T20:11:44.05",
"updatedAt": "2022-11-19T20:11:44.05"
}

Specifically, we are not sure how to retrieve the fields name="document"; filename="other-doc.jpg" from input, store it and return in Get call.

Referred to the foll links but did not help.

https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/policy-expressions/README.md
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of how you are doing this in APIM

Comment: Sorry not reputable enough! But i am using the expressions given in Policy snippets on GitHub for Blob storage. Link at the end of main post. hope that helps

Comment: which post url you are using? You can add the screenshot as a link in your post

Comment: https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob 
  given in the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=azure-ad